# How to pivot table and combine rows based on a condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following table produced by the following SQL:

```
select userid, name, sirname, age from Users
```

[image]

I am wondering what would the best way be to convert this to something that looks like:

[image]

Would `partition by` + `distinct` be the most efficient way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT userid, [0] AS name, [1] AS sirname, age
FROM users 
PIVOT
(MAX(name)
FOR sirname IN ([0],[1]))AS p
```

Answer (score 0):

I would just suggest aggregation:

```
select userid, max(case when simame = 0 then name end) as name,
       max(case when simmame = 1 then name end) as simame,
       age
from t
group by userid, age;
```

Comment: Thanks. Hmmm, I feel partition by + distinct would be more natural because they allow the selection of columns not in the partition clause (unlike group by)

Comment: @s5s . . . Because you changed the question, I changed the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to suggest, that the most natural solution would be:

```
SELECT
    u1.id
    ,u1.name
    ,u2.name as sirname
    ,u1.age
FROM users u1
INNER JOIN users u2 ON u1.id=u2.id and u2.sirname=1
WHERE
  u1.sirname=0
```

even more so, as this approach can easily be modelled to cope with situations where one of the two names may be missing.